# Trouble with proof that simple random walk is a Markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

[image]

I am having trouble understanding where these last two expressions come from, namely:

$ P(S_n = i) = p^{\frac{n-j}{2} + \frac{i}{2}} q^{\frac{n-j}{2} - \frac{i}{2}} $

$ P(S_n = -i) = p^{\frac{n-j}{2} - \frac{i}{2}} q^{\frac{n-j}{2} + \frac{i}{2}} $

Shouldn't there be a binomial coefficient somewhere since we are calculating the number of successes in $n-j$ trials?

Example: let $j=0$, $n=10$, $i=4$.

Here event $S_{10} = 4$ could occur in multiple ways:

$S_1 = 1, S_2 = 2, \dots , S_7 = 7, S_8 = 6, S_9 = 5, S_{10} = 4$

OR

$S_1 = -1, S_2 = -2, S_3 = -3, S_4 = -2, S_5 = -1, \dots , S_9 = 3, S_{10} = 4$

So not only am I confused about where the probabilities come from but I have no intuition for it because there is no binomial coefficient present.

Comment: Even if there were binomial coefficients, they would cancel

Comment: But you know all the absolute values of $|S_1|,|S_2|,\ldots,|S_n|$ and the calculation is only after the last time you left $0$, so there are only two possibilities: you went up from $0$ and arrived at $S_n=i$ with $S_{j+1}=1, S_{j+2}=2, \ldots, S_n=i$ or you went down and arrived at $S_n=-i$ with $S_{j+1}=-1, S_{j+2}=-2, \ldots, S_n=-i$ since the route is determined by the absolute values, so there is only one possibility for each.

Comment: Your two example routes are not both possible as one has $|S_9|=5$ and the other $|S_9|=3$ and you are conditioning on knowing $|S_9|$.  Your second example route is also not possible with $j=0$ since if you start by going down with $S_{j+1}=-1<0$ then you cannot reach $S_{10}=4>0$ without passing through $0$ and that would contradict your value of $j$.